# How to take the log of all elements of a list

Tags: python, arrays

I have an array

```
x = [1500, 1049.8, 34, 351, etc]
```

How can I take log_10() of the entire array?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
from math import log
[log(y,10) for y in x]
```

Comment: Or use `log10` ;) `This is usually more accurate than log(x, 10).`

Comment: This works to answer the poster's question, and it is efficient, but I was trying to take the logarithm of a 2 dimensional array. For that I used `numpy.log10` instead.

Answer (score 48):

[numpy](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.log10.html) will do that for you.

```
import numpy
numpy.log10(mat)
```

**Note**

`mat` does not have to be a numpy array for this to work, and `numpy` should be faster than using a list comprehension as other answers suggest.

Comment: I have no doubt that NumPy will do this, and do it very quickly, but bear in mind it's a little bit overkill to install NumPy for some simple scripting.

Comment: who said it's for some simple scripting?

Comment: @mutzmatron Nobody, I suppose, but the question has a beginner feel to it, and when I was starting out, I used tiny, tiny problems to reduce the number of things I could mess up at any one time. Just thought I'd point it out. FTR, I upvoted you since you gave a good answer that wasn't the same as the like 20 of us who all jumped in with a list comp as our answer.

Comment: @HankGay - hehehe yeah I noticed how the list comp answers poured in. Cheers for the upvote, and I do agree that in a sense the pythonic way would be to use the list comp and I use them a lot.

Comment: Using `numpy.log10` worked for my 2 dimensional array, while `math.log10` would not.

Answer (score 9):

The simpliest way is to use a [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)

---

**Example:**

```
>>> x = [1500, 1049.8, 34, 351]
>>> import math
>>> [math.log10(i) for i in x]
[3.1760912590556813, 3.021106568432122, 1.5314789170422551, 2.545307116465824]
>>>
```

Another way is to use the [map](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#map) function

---

**Example:**

```
>>> map(math.log10, x)
[3.1760912590556813, 3.021106568432122, 1.5314789170422551, 2.545307116465824]
>>>
```

Answer (score 9):

You could also use the `map` builtin function:

```
import math
new_list = map(math.log10, old_list)
```

This will probably be insignificantly faster than the list comprehension.  I add it here mainly to show the similarity between the two.

**EDIT** (in response to the comment by @HankGay)

To prove that map is slightly faster in this case, I've written a small benchmark:

```
import timeit

for i in range(10):
    t=timeit.timeit("map(math.log10,a)",setup="import math; a=range(1,100)")
    print "map",t
    t=timeit.timeit("[math.log10(x) for x in a]",setup="import math; a=range(1,100)")
    print "list-comp",t
```

Here are the results on my laptop (OS-X 10.5.8, CPython 2.6):

```
map 24.5870189667
list-comp 32.556563139
map 23.2616219521
list-comp 32.0040669441
map 23.9995992184
list-comp 33.2653431892
map 24.1171340942
list-comp 33.0399811268
map 24.3114480972
list-comp 33.5015368462
map 24.296754837
list-comp 33.5107491016
map 24.0294749737
list-comp 33.5332789421
map 23.7013399601
list-comp 33.1543111801
map 24.41685009
list-comp 32.9259850979
map 24.1111209393
list-comp 32.9298729897
```

It is important to realize that speed isn't everything though.  "readability matters".  If `map` creates something that is harder to read, definitely go for a list comprehension.

Comment: I would be utterly shocked if `map` were faster than a list comp, at least on CPython. The CPython implementation of list comps is optimized out the wazoo. If I get some downtime, I might go set up a micro-benchmark, which, as we all know, are fabulously useful :-)

Comment: @HankGay -- Check out my update.  For this simple test case, `map` is nearly 50% faster than an equivalent list comp.

Comment: @mgilson Weird. I'm on my work machine, so it's Snow Leopard w/ `Python 2.6.1 (r261:67515, Jun 24 2010, 21:47:49) `, and my numbers are basically showing list comps to be *ever* so slightly faster, but the difference is so small I doubt it is statistically significant: [my code](https://gist.github.com/3178199) yielded 
`lc: 1.03603506088, map: 1.04137277603`, `lc: 1.16478681564, map: 1.21709990501`, and `lc: 0.909293889999, map: 1.15685892105`

Comment: @HankGay -- I reran my test giving the list comp a slight "advantage" (`from math import log10`) and `[log10(x) for x in a]` and map still won, but by a much more slim margin (map ~ 23s, list_comp ~ 25s).  I wonder if our timings have anything to do with 64bit vs 32bit (I've seen that matter on occasion).  I can also try my benchmark on Ubuntu Linux -- I'll give it a shot and get back to you...

Comment: @mgilson 64-bit vs. 32-bit is a great point and something I didn't even consider. This just goes to show why I pretty much always tell people to profile before they bother to "optimize".

Comment: @HankGay -- on my (64-bit) Ubuntu machine (intel i7 FWIW), `map` is still edging out list-comp (but only by ~10%) for both versions (`import math` and `from math import log10`).  list size could also be a factor.  My list contains 99 elements whereas yours had 5.

Comment: And, perhaps this link ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1247486/python-list-comprehension-vs-map ) should serve as the definitive reference on the subject ...

Answer (score 5):

```
import math
x = [1500, 1049.8, 34, 351]
y = [math.log10(num) for num in x]
```

This is called a [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions). What it is doing is creating a new list whose elements are the results of applying [`math.log10`](http://docs.python.org/library/math.html#math.log10) to the corresponding element in the original `list`, which is not an [`array`](http://docs.python.org/library/array.html#array.array), btw.